# get error: This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used By list.add

Tags: flutter

here is error I got:
This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used By list

So I dont get the point, why in my case it does not work, thanks for any clue

```
  List<Widget> homePages = [
    buildCoverWidget(),
    buildCoverWidget(),
  ];

   List<Widget> homePagesAddAddPersonPage(){
    homePagesWithAddPersonPage = homePages.add(AddPersonPage()); // here is error .add
    return homePagesWithAddPersonPage;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add` just adds it. It doesn't return a new list. So just do

```
List<Widget> homePagesAddAddPersonPage(){
  homePages.add(AddPersonPage());
  return homePages;
}
```

If you don't want to modify `homePages` you could do

```
List<Widget> homePagesAddAddPersonPage(){
  return [...homePages, AddPersonPage()];
}
```

Comment: Hi Ivo, thanks for your quick and correct answer, I will set it as answer as soon as I can!